# multiple windows not showing up upon execution ( 1 out of 3)

Tags: javafx

quick question,

why are my multiple windows not appearing from this code?

also any tips on how to make the circle's diameter increase only by the stage's resolution when the window is increased in size; anyway of doing this internally through "circ3."

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Circles extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Circle circ = new Circle();
    circ.setStroke(Color.DARKBLUE);
    circ.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
    circ.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(10));
    circ.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().subtract(20));
    circ.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().subtract(20));
    circ.setRadius(20);
    pane.getChildren().add(circ);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Bottom Right");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


    Pane pane2 = new Pane();
    Circle circ2 = new Circle();
    circ2.setStroke(Color.PEACHPUFF);
    circ2.setFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN);
    circ2.centerXProperty().bind(pane2.widthProperty().divide(2));
    circ2.centerYProperty().bind(pane2.heightProperty().subtract(20));
    circ2.setRadius(20);
    pane2.getChildren().add(circ2);
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(pane2, 200, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Bottom Centered");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
    primaryStage.show();


    Pane pane3 = new Pane();
    Circle circ3 = new Circle();
    circ3.setStroke(Color.PEACHPUFF);
    circ3.setFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN);
    circ3.centerXProperty().bind(pane3.widthProperty().subtract(150));
    circ3.centerYProperty().bind(pane3.heightProperty().divide(2));
    circ3.setRadius(150);

    //size (circle diameter) needs to scale with width resolution 
    pane3.getChildren().add(circ3);
    //boilerplate
    Scene scene3 = new Scene(pane3, 300, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Radius / Width ");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene3);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have one window, `primaryStage`. Where are the other windows you are referring to?

Comment: do i create a new method for each window I have?

Comment: Again, not sure what you mean by "for each window I have". You only have one window in this code. If you want more windows, create more `Stage`s.

Comment: ok sorry for saying this wrong, for each "scene"; i wanted show all 3 scenes at the same time

Comment: I guess I'm still confused. Do you want multiple windows showing? I assume you realize that a window in JavaFX is represented by the `Stage` class, right? So if what you're saying is that you want multiple windows you have to create additional `Stage`s. I don't really get what you're missing.

Comment: OK; i got it to work with Stage stage2 = new Stage(); (and Stage stage3 = new Stage(); ) 

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the circle change size with the window size using bindings:

```
Pane pane3 = new Pane();
Circle circ3 = new Circle();
circ3.setStroke(Color.PEACHPUFF);
circ3.setFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN);
circ3.centerXProperty().bind(pane3.widthProperty().divide(2));
circ3.centerYProperty().bind(pane3.heightProperty().divide(2));
circ3.radiusProperty().bind(pane3.widthProperty().divide(2));
```